# How to calculate the percentage difference between two measurements in a table on Power BI?

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, dax

I am working on a Power BI report and I have a table like this:

[image]

I would like to add a column "`GP %`" where I will have inside the difference between the columns "Gross Euros" in percentage.
Difference between FY20, FY21 and FY22 each time.

My date table is like this :

[image]

The "`Gross Euros`" column uses a measurement I made in my model with Visual Studio.
As it is not a column but a measure, is it possible to make a DAX formula in Power BI to have this difference in percentage?

I have this now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using SamePeiordLastYear.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sameperiodlastyear-function-dax

Reference: https://carldesouza.com/creating-a-power-bi-chart-comparing-each-year-vs-previous-year/

Comment: The problem is that I can't do SUM on my measure but only on a column....

Comment: You do not have to do a sum, use the measure directly.

Comment: Like this : Diff = CALCULATE([Euro Gross Amount], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('date'[date])) ?

Comment: Yes, please try that.

Comment: This puts me in huge percentages... Maybe a problem in my date table?

Comment: Please update Diff% to:

DIFF% = DIVIDE(([Euro Gross Amount] - CALCULATE ([Euro Gross Amount], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('date'[date])), CALCULATE ([Euro Gross Amount], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('date'[date]), 0)

This should do the trick.

Comment: I modified the request because yours was in error, I put a screenshot